# Make function calls sequentially from a array of objects without waiting for result

Tags: javascript

I have an array of objects. For all the objects inside that array, i have to execute a series of function  and that result should be sent back to callee. I want to execute these functions for those objects sequentially or paralleled without waiting for the result.

for example:
I have

```js
const arr = [{...},{...},{...},...{...}];
function exeArr(obj) {
  function f1(){...},
  function f2(){...}
  return result
}
```

Comment: Are we talking about async functions, like API requests?

Comment: use Array.map()

Comment: _"result should be sent back to callee"_ and _"without waiting for the result"_ seem to be at odds. It's not clear what you're asking. Could you please provide some concrete examples of the inputs and expected outputs from this application?

Comment: `const ser = [{..},{..},...{..}]

ser.forEach( el => {
 const op = f1(el);
})


f1(args) {
 
 f2() {
 },
 f3() {
 }
 f4() {
 } 
 return result;
}`
 
 I have to execute the function f1 for the objects inside the service array. In the above scenario, the code is synchrounous, I  want it to be asynchronous. Next object should call the function without waiting for the result.

Answer (score 0):

Use async code execution with `setTimeout`:

```
setTimeout(() => exeArr(obj), 0);
setTimeout(f1, 0);
setTimeout(f2, 0);
...
```

Answer (score -1):

not sure if this async await is what you need , but you can try it :

```
      let logObj = async (obj) => {
      for (var i in obj) {
            document.write(obj[i]);
        }
    }

    let myArr = [{a: "a" , w:'w' }, { b: "b" , u:'u' }, { c: "c" , t:'t' }, { d: "d" }, { e: "e" }];
    let exeArr =  arr => {
      arr.map(async obj => {
          await logObj(obj);
      });
    };

    exeArr(myArr);
```

Comment: my perception for the above example is, objects inside the array was processed synchronously. Async runs in the background, executing all the objects one by one, waiting for the result. Please correct if i'm wrong. I want those objects to call those function without waiting for the result

Comment: @VarunDravid when functions are used Asynchronously , program doesn't wait for them to finish to run next line , so in the example above , function logObj gets objects and starts looping in them , when calling multiple times , it executes each one separately and doesn't wait for first object to finish to execute next one . however if you want to become sure about this , i recommend you to  trace your code using console to see if it works or not , but i guess it does